# Dark mode documentation center

Tags: front-end, files-and-directories

I saw some posts that modify or add some Mathematica files to change the interface of Mathematica's notebooks. Are there files that determine the background color of the documentation center ? I am using DarkMode from the Mathematica function repository and it is difficult to look at the documentation center after. My solutions so far have been to invert the colors on my screen with keyboard shortcuts or search in my browser.

Comment: Browser doc search is probably the best option until WRI solves this itself...